# DateTime.Now giving incorrect time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, azure

I'm developing an application in Visual Studio using C#. When I create a new instance of an object I want to attach the current date and time to it. Using `DateTime.Now` the time is off by one hour.

I presume its a time-zone or daylight saving issue. I tried calling `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()` right before `DateTime.Now` but got the same result. How do I resolve this?

Comment: please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776093/datetime-now-and-culture-timezone-specific

Comment: DateTime.Now returns the current *local* time based on the culture of the machine. What type of date are you trying to get? Local? UTC?

Comment: [`DateTime.Now` gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the local time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx). How do you obtain the value and what makes you think it is incorrect?

Comment: Its a website application that allows you to add updates. All updates can be displayed as a list which shows the time/date the update was added. When I add a new update the time is off by one hour.

Comment: Ok I've tried running the application on the local host and there's no problem. Th issue is obviously with the server. I'm using Windows Azure.

Comment: Then it sounds to me like you'll need to give up on using local time. Use UTC internally, and convert it to a specific time zone (*not* the server's configured system time zone) when you want to display it?

Comment: on azure, do you have your own dedicated machine where you have access to the time settings in windows, or is it a shared environment?

Answer (score 12):

You should use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now` to avoid time zone issues (`DateTime.Now` uses the time zone of the server), then you can convert the UTC value to the user's time zone.